# Using javascript library with Maximo

Tags: javascript, dojo, maximo

I am trying to integrate Maximo with javascript based spreedsheets. I have created a jsp page with all references needed to the js files ( same is working fine in a simple html page out of maximo ).
Once the system loads the file, it throw error that module is not defined.
Maximo uses Dojo as primary javascript library and it seems i have to add a reference somewhere in Dojo files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would love to know more about this use case. Sounds interesting.

Comment: well, i'm trying to create a custom control that enable the user to enter data in an excel sheet fashion , something like this one "https://maxls-dataload.com/" . So i found that javascript that render a spreadsheet grid , created a custom jsp file -> configured component and control registry, added it to PR application and then this problem showed up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jExcel that you are trying to use requires the [jSuites](https://jsuites.net/v4/) module.